# Why/How to fix selected option in DOM different from screen in IE11

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-11, browser-history

I have a page that has JavaScript that executes `history.go(-1); return false;` to go to a previous page when a "Return" button is pushed.  The page displays the correct selected option on the initial page load but when going to the next page that has the "Return" button and then going back, the selected option displayed on the screen becomes a random value that is not the same as what the DOM shows.  Below are screenshots of the progression and then my `sortSelect()` code at the bottom.  This issue does not occur in Edge or Chrome but does in IE 11.

I'm ultimately wanting to know how to remedy this issue such that what is displayed on the screen reflects what the DOM is saying is the selected option.

**Before Sort on initial page load (correct option displays):**

[image: Before Sort on initial page load]

**After Sort on initial page load (correct option displays):**

[image: After Sort on initial page load]

**Before Sort after history.go(-1) from next page (incorrect option displays):**

[image: Before Sort after history.go(-1) from next page]

**After Sort after history.go(-1) from next page (incorrect option displays):**

[image: After Sort after history.go(-1) from next page]

**Sort Select method:**

```
$.fn.sortSelect = function() {
    this.each(function(index, selectElement) {
        if (selectElement && selectElement.tagName.toUpperCase() === "SELECT") {
            var val = $(selectElement).val();
            // get the child options
            var options = $(selectElement).children('option');

            // sort'em
            options.sort(function(a, b) {
                if ( ! a.text) {
                    a.text = "";
                }
                if ( ! b.text) {
                    b.text = "";
                }
                if (a.text.toLowerCase() > b.text.toLowerCase()) {
                    return 1;
                } else if (a.text.toLowerCase() < b.text.toLowerCase()) {
                    return -1;
                } else {
                    return 0;
                }
            });

            // purge the select element and append the sorted options.
            $(selectElement).empty();
            $(selectElement).append(options);
            $(selectElement).val(val);
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: Your code seems to rely on `<option>` elements having a `.text` property. Are you sure that's true in IE?

Comment: Also [check out `.localeCompare`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare)

Comment: @Pointy doesn't the `( ! a.text)` establish the `.text` property?

Comment: Well sure, it initializes it to the empty string, so the sort won't do anything based on the actual DOM elements if `.text` starts off empty.

Comment: To get the text in an element, you'd use `.textContent` in most browsers and `.innerText` in older versions of IE.

Comment: @Pointy using this sort doesn't fix the issue so I don't think it has to do with the sort - `options.sort(function(a, b) { return a.textContent.toLocaleLowerCase().localeCompare(b.textContent.toLocaleLowerCase()); });`

Comment: But interestingly commenting out just the `options.sort...` does result in the selected option and what's displayed being correct on `history.go(-1)`